# npm choose global install directory

Tags: installation, npm

I want to install npm dependencies from a package.json in the current directory, but I want to install them to a different directory.

Can I make this setting (install directory of node_modules) project specific, so as to not interfere with my other projects?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `--prefix`.

```
npm install --prefix new/path/node_modules
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix

NOTE: Important, that there is a node_modules folder